# What is the syntax error in this wordpress code?

Tags: wordpress

I am developing wordpress site and I got this error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas11_data02/07/3672907/html/wp-content/themes/primer/inc/template-tags.php on line 51
```

here is coding for that

```
printf('<a href="%1$s" class="custom-logo-link" %2$s>%3$s</a>',
        esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),
        $custom_logo_id ? 'rel="home" itemprop="url"' : 'style="display:none;"',
        $custom_logo_id ? wp_get_attachment_image( $custom_logo_id, 'full', false, $args ) : '<img class="custom-logo"/>'
    );
```

So what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
printf('<a href="%1$s" class="custom-logo-link" %2$s>%3$s</a>',
```

to this

```
printf("<a href=\"%1$s\" class=\"custom-logo-link\" %2$s>%3$s</a>",
```